# Android ImageView selector cannot displayed normal

Tags: android, selector, drawable

I need to show some `drawable selector` on the `listView`, and I use `DrawableSelector` to implement this effect. **But in some devices, it will work as expected, while in others, its not,** and the detailed effect would look like the following picture that I captured from the devices that Exception happened:[image]

The following are the code to implement this :

```
<selector>
   <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_hovered"></item>
   <item android:drawable="img_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong, thank you advance.

Comment: Try adding margin from top

Comment: Can you give me some more detailed information about this? does the "adding margin from top" meaning adding margin to this selector in the  layout file or something else?

Comment: Vise versa add the margin from bottom if your adding the value in selector